# JoomGallery.net | image ordering asc

Tags: joomla3.0

i would like to use this simple image slider for the joomgallery for my art students:

https://github.com/danielhpavey/joomgallery-slider

the only problem is the ordering. how do i get an ascending image ordering by id and not by filename ?

thanks peter

```html
<?php
class images
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $file = JPATH_ROOT. '/components/com_joomgallery/interface.php';
        if(!file_exists($file)){
            JError::raiseError(500, 'JoomGallery seems not to be installed');
        } else {
            require_once $file;
            $this ->interface = new JoomInterface();
        }
    }
    public function getFirstImage()
    {
        $images = $this ->talkToJoomgallery();
        return $images[0];
 
    }
    public function getImages()
    {
        $images = $this ->talkToJoomgallery();
        return $images;
    }
    public function talkToJoomgallery()
    {
        
        $images = $this ->interface ->getPicsByCategory( $this ->categoryid );
        $imagepath = $this ->joomgalleryImagePath();
        $theimages = array();
        $c = 0;
        foreach ($images as $i){
            $theimages[$c]=  array( 
                    'imgpath' => JURI::base() . $imagepath . $i->catpath . '/' . $i->imgfilename 
                    ,'imgtitle' => $i->imgtitle
                    ,'imgtext' => $i->imgtext
                    );
        
            $c ++;
        }
        shuffle($theimages);
                    
        return $theimages;
    }
    private function joomgalleryImagePath()
    {
        
        return $this ->interface ->getJConfig( 'jg_pathoriginalimages' );
    }
    public function __set($property, $value){
    $this->$property = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images are loaded according to image id only but this command is reindexing the array i.e `shuffle($theimages)`;
You can comment out that line by

```
//shuffle($theimages)
```

Also for ordering images you can change this line in helper.php file

```
$images = $this->interface->getPicsByCategory($this->categoryid);
```

to

```
$images = $this->interface->getPicsByCategory($this->categoryid,null,'ordering' );
```

This will do the ordering of images the way you did drag and drop of images at the joomla administrator backend.

**UPDATE AS PER YOUR LATEST QUERY**

Suppose you want to add a param value (sorting) that can be controlled through admin. You ned to change the xml file `mod_joomgallery_slider.xml`
 Just add a new field like this

```html
<field
 name = "sorting"
 type = "radio"
 label = "Sorting"
 description = "Sort by Ordering or random"
 default = "ordering"
 >
 <option value = "ordering">Ordering</option>
 <option value = "rand()">Random</option>
 </field>
```

Next to get the param in helper.php file then change the function `talkToJoomgallery()` like this

```
public function talkToJoomgallery()
    {
        //Externally calling a module param
        jimport( 'joomla.html.parameter' );
        jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
        $module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_joomgallery_slider');
        $moduleParams = new JRegistry();
        $moduleParams->loadString($module->params);
        $sorting = $moduleParams->get( 'sorting' );

        $images = $this ->interface ->getPicsByCategory( $this ->categoryid,null,$sorting );
        $imagepath = $this ->joomgalleryImagePath();

        $theimages = array();
        $c = 0;
        foreach ($images as $i){
            $theimages[$c]=  array( 
                    'imgpath' => JURI::base() . $imagepath . $i->catpath . '/' . $i->imgfilename 
                    ,'imgtitle' => $i->imgtitle
                    ,'imgtext' => $i->imgtext
                    );

            $c ++;
        }
        //var_dump($theimages); exit;
        //shuffle($theimages);

        return $theimages;

    }
```

**UPDATE: To display 2 slider modules on a single page.**

Some files needs to changed:

In mod_joomgallery_slider.php file change this line at top

```
include('helper.php');
```

To

```
include_once('helper.php');
```

This ensures that the file is included once.

Another change will be to remove the function `imageText` in default.php and including it in helper.php class else a `function redeclaration error` will be thrown. But now the default.php file still give error, as function `imageText` will be not defined, but you already added that function to helper.php. So default.php will only work if you change

```
echo imageText( $i, $params );
```

To

```
echo $image->imageText( $i, $params );// You are calling helper object
```

Remember to change in both if and else conditions.

Comment: thanks for the quick response and the helpful answer. Maybe my question was a little confusing. i already realized that "shuffle($theimages)" shuffles the images by filename. so i asked for a solution for "ascending image ordering by id" to be sure to get the ordering of joomgallery itself. what i need is that the slider takes the image/picture order of joomgallery. so changing the order by drag and drop there changes the order in the slideshow.  thanks peter

Comment: @PeterReill Please check the answer again, I have modified it as per your requirement.

Comment: @PeterReill You are welcome and kindly mark this as solved.

Comment: we inserted a field in the xml file with the name "sorting" and the values "ordering" & "rand()". Now we try to get this  value in helper.php file. but all attempts fail to insert it in your code line $images = $this->interface->getPicsByCategory($this->categoryid,null,'ordering' );
How do we get the value of param "sorting" instead of the 'ordering'? thanks a lot

Comment: Thats unbelievable!!! You are great. Thanks for this addition. One of my students experienced a problem when she trie to show the module twice on one page. It gives her a white screen. We couldn't find a solution by google. Do you have any idea? Anyway, thank you ver much

Comment: @PeterReill Updated. Plz check.